# Why my gatsby app shows Unknown argument 'frontmatter' error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I'm still new in react.I just to make my portfolio built with good tech.I'm interested to gatsbyjs.For now,i got an error.It says
Unknown argument 'frontmatter'
I have no idea about this.Is this related to the graphql or the gatsbyjs?
can someone help me to fix this?

i was watching youtube tutorial from "LevelUp Tutorial" channel.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VxVKMJThh04&list=PLLnpHn493BHHfoINKLELxDch3uJlSapxg&index=5

```
import React from 'react'
import Helmet from 'react-helmet'
import { graphql } from "gatsby"

export default function Template({ data }) {
    const { markdownRemark: post } = data; //sama dengan const post=data.markdownRemark
    // const { markdownRemark } = data // data.markdownRemark holds our post data


    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{post.frontmatter.title}</h1>
            <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: post.html }} />
        </div>
    )

}

export const postQuery = graphql`
query BlogPostByPath($path : String!){
    markdownRemark(frontmatter:{path: { eq:$path}}){
        html
        frontmatter{
            path
            title
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Go to your gatsby-config.js.

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
  options: {
    name: `pages`,
    path: `${__dirname}/src/pages`,
  },
},
```

make sure there is(are) *.md file(s) in your pages folder or sub-folders.

That fixed my problem, unknown argument 'frontmatter'. If it does not work for you, check out the tutorial. [Creating a Blog with Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/blog/2017-07-19-creating-a-blog-with-gatsby/#writing-our-first-markdown-blog-post)

Comment: You are right.I didn't attach the config.thank you so much for the help hugh.

Comment: than could you put this answer as the right answer @galihindra